# Best way to provide the fingerprint comparison in the server side

Tags: c#, database, memory-management, asp.net-web-api, fingerprint

I'm going to provide the fingerprint authentication from server side via WebAPI. The below code is the fingerprint comparison part.

```
var allFingerprints = container.Fingerprints.OrderByDescending(p=>p.FingerprintID);

List<Fmd> fmdList = new List<Fmd>();

foreach (var fp in allFingerprints)
{
    fmdList.Add(Fmd.DeserializeXml(fp.FMD));
}

IdentifyResult identifyResult = Comparison.Identify(customerFmd, 0, fmdList, thresholdScore, 2);
```

If the small amount(<3000) fingerprints are in the DB, I think it will be OK to read the fingerprint from DB and compare it. But if the amount of fingerprints is getting bigger and the server get a lot of API Calls from clients later, what is the best way to read fingerprint from DB and compare it? Do I have to keep the fingerprint list in the memory and compare it? Thank you for your valuable comments in advance.

Comment: I have same question. facing exactly the same issue with my windows application

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF some information will be in memory automaticaly. But if you want to make your own structure, use dictionary instead of a list. Also you can use redis for this purpose.

Comment: What if there are 1 million records and we want to query it..  Is it feasible to get it all in a dictionary and then pass it to Identify() function ?

Comment: I am not sure. You need to test that, and see performance. Maybe redis is better option, but dictionary is the easiest to implement.